# Pharo3.0 headless image with RFB/VNC enabled

Tags: macos, pharo, headless

Please find below the script i am using to run pharo seaside image headless on mac. its pharo3.0 image downloaded for mac os.

```
 #!/bin/bash



RT="$PWD/Pharo3.0.app/Contents"

#exec $0 "$RT/MacOS/Pharo"    "$RT/Resources/Pharo3.0.image"

exec "$PWD/Pharo3.0.app/Contents/MacOS/Pharo" --headless --nohandlers "$PWD/Pharo3.0.app/Contents/Resources/Pharo3.0.image" --no-default-preferences --no-quit
```

The script is placed on the same folder as the Pharo3.0.app and it executes pretty well.

1) Can anyone verify this and let me know if i am doing it the right way to start a headless image for deployment?

Also i have an RFB server set up in the image for debugging. When i connect to it and do a right click i get the below error

```
RFB: caught ConnectionClosed: Connection close while waiting for data.SubclassResponsibility: NonInteractiveUIManager had the subclass responsibility to implement #newMenuIn:for:

NonInteractiveUIManager(Object)>>subclassResponsibility

NonInteractiveUIManager(UIManager)>>newMenuIn:for:

PluggableTextMorph(ScrollPane)>>getMenu:

PluggableTextMorph>>yellowButtonActivity:

SmalltalkEditor(TextEditor)>>mouseUp:

TextMorphForEditView(TextMorph)>>mouseUp: in Block: [ editor mouseUp: evt ]

TextMorphForEditView(TextMorph)>>handleInteraction:

TextMorphForEditView>>handleInteraction:

TextMorphForEditView(TextMorph)>>mouseUp:

TextMorphForEditView>>mouseUp:

TextMorphForEditView(Morph)>>handleMouseUp:

MouseButtonEvent>>sentTo:

TextMorphForEditView(Morph)>>handleEvent:

TextMorphForEditView(Morph)>>handleFocusEvent:

HandMorph>>sendFocusEvent:to:clear: in Block: [ ...

BlockClosure>>on:do:

WorldMorph(PasteUpMorph)>>becomeActiveDuring:

HandMorph>>sendFocusEvent:to:clear:

HandMorph>>sendEvent:focus:clear:

HandMorph>>sendMouseEvent:

HandMorph>>handleEvent:

MouseClickState>>handleEvent:from:

HandMorph>>handleEvent:

HandMorph>>processEvents

WorldState>>doOneCycleNowFor: in Block: [ :h | ...

Array(SequenceableCollection)>>do:

WorldState>>handsDo:

WorldState>>doOneCycleNowFor:

WorldState>>doOneCycleFor:

WorldMorph>>doOneCycle
```

Please let me know what i am doing wrong.

TIA,

thushar

Answer (score 1):

Looks good to me.

The problem with RFB is actually *not* RFB itself but the `NonInteractiveUIManager`. That class should implement `#newMenuIn:for:`. My suggestion: You should not use the `NonInteractiveUIManager` with RFB. When you start RFB (or alternatively, when you receive a connection), you should do something like this:

```
UIManager default: MorphicUIManager new.
"let the connection run, when it's done, use the other one:"
UIManager default: NonInteractiveUIManager.
```

You should revert to NonInteractiveUIManager when you don't interact with the image to ensure that you don't have windows and dialogs and debuggers popping up in the headless image.